# mvvm add button next to datagrid in rowdetails

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

First of all I am trying to follow the MVVM design pattern.

I have a datagrid. When a row is clicked upon the rowdetails become visible. In the row details I have another datagrid, let call this sub datagrid. In the sub datagrid one of the columns is a checkbox column where the user can update the column. The rowdetails has a datatemplate in App.xaml.

However I want to add a button next to the sub datagrid so if a user clicks the button it will tick all the boxes in the checkbox column rather than them having to click each row. I can add a button to the rowdetail datatemplate but not sure how to do the binding? I don't know how to achieve this keeping to MVVM.

**Main Window - with datagrid**

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding HldLogEQCurr, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          Style="{StaticResource DataGridTemplate1}"
                          ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DG_ColumnHeaderCenter1}"                                            
                          RowStyle="{StaticResource DG_Row1}"
                          CellStyle="{StaticResource DG_Cell1}"                                    
                          RowHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DG_RowHeader1}"
                          RowDetailsTemplate="{StaticResource DG_RowDetailRGHTSEX}" 
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"                           
                          Background="Silver" 
                          Margin="50,50,50,50"                              
                          CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                          CanUserAddRows="False"
                          RowHeaderWidth="30">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date Entered" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding DateEntered, StringFormat={}\{0:dd-MMM-yy\}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinWidth="75"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date Effective" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding DateEffective, StringFormat={}\{0:dd-MMM-yy\}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinWidth="75"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sedol" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Security.Sedol}" MinWidth="75"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Security.Name}" MinWidth="200"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ratio" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding RatioNew}" MinWidth="75"/>

                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

**App.xaml**

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="DG_RowDetailRGHTSEX">
        <Grid x:Name="RowDetailGrid"            
              Margin="5"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Border HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Height="250"
                    CornerRadius="5">
                <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Transparent"/>
                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Transparent"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="400"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Margin="5,5,5,5"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               FontSize="12"
                               FontWeight="Bold"
                               Foreground="Black" 
                               Text="Select action to take">
                    </TextBlock>
                    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Funds,  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"                                                                  
                              RowStyle="{StaticResource DG_Row}"  
                              ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DG_ColumnHeader}" 
                              RowHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DG_RowHeaderNested}"
                              CellStyle="{StaticResource DG_Cell}" 
                              Background="Silver"
                              HorizontalGridLinesBrush="LightGray"
                              VerticalGridLinesBrush="LightGray"
                              CanUserAddRows="False"
                              CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                              Margin="50,5,5,20"
                              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Fund Code" Binding="{Binding Code}" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="75"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Fund Code SS" Binding="{Binding CodeSS}" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="75"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Number of Rights" Binding="{Binding NewNominal, StringFormat={}{0:N0}}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Take Cash" Binding="{Binding OptionOne, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="False">

                            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
                            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Take Stock" Binding="{Binding OptionTwo, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="False">

                            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>

                    <Grid Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>                                                     

                    </Grid>

                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Why dont you add your xaml so that it is possible to help you without wild guessing?

Comment: @Domysee, I have added my code